# flutter why the app crashing when using a lot of image asset

Tags: android, flutter, performance, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCuw4.gif)I used 52 images in the assets and they were jpg and the application was crashing and I pagination gridview.builder and also the problem happened the same !

Comment: Would you let me know some code and error message?

Comment: there is no any error message

Comment: W/Looper  (12135): PerfMonitor longMsg : seq=360 plan=11:36:22.533 late=2ms wall=1129ms running=12ms runnable=13ms io=1054ms reclaim=4ms h=android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler c=android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver procState=2
W/Looper  (12135): PerfMonitor doFrame : time=1129ms vsyncFrame=0 latency=2ms procState=2
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it by using cacheHeight and cacheWidth in Image.asset